# cron job that does not run : starring python, phantomjs, ec2 box

Tags: python, phantomjs, cron

Problem: I'm using the python-crontab package to add a cron job. This command never gets executed. Though, it works fine when run directly from the CLI. The script is supposed to run phantomjs through subprocess, take a snapshot and email it out (sendmail).

This is the job that I'm trying to run:

```
04 23 * * * /home/ec2-user/drive2/anaconda/bin/python /home/ec2-user/drive4/screen/screenshot.py > /home/ec2-user/drive4/screen/log.out
```

What I've tried:

1. added the job with `sudo crontab -e`. Did not see any errors there so I'm assuming that the job is syntactically correct.
2. All paths in the job are absolute.
3. All scripts/executables involved are set to 777 in terms of write-access.
4. Added PATH and SHELL variables inside crontab to no effect.
5. Made sure that the path ends with newline.

Can anyone please save my day and give me a solution to this conundrum ?

Comment: Something in the log? `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: @ArtjomB. I checked in /var/log/cron and found only vanilla edit/close messages. That command gives me a : grep: /var/log/syslog: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Timezone was the culprit. Updated it and rebooting the system and it worked fine.